# iOS converting date string with am, pm to NSDate (Device setting with 24 hour format)

Tags: ios

I have date time string like this.

> 20 Feb 2017 03:32PM //This time is singapore time. So I need to choose singapore time zone

And I try to convert to NSDate like this.

```
NSDate *redeemDate = [NSDate dateWithString:currentDateString formatString:@"dd MMM yyyy hh:mma" timeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:8*3600]];
```

I use this library though. But it is also same if I manually format. 
https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools

If device use 12 hour format, it is okay but if it use 24 hour format, I got nil. May I know why? I thought may be it is because of **hh** and I change to **HH**. But it is also not okay.

Comment: Where are you getting the string from?  Is the string ALWAYS in that format or does it change based on the user's device?

Comment: It is from my backend. It won't change based on user's device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HH:mm => will look like 00:12, 23:00... this has 24 hour format.

hh:mm => will look like 01:00Am, 02:00Am,...01:00pm this has 12 hour format.

So you have to convert to the appropriate format if you want to display in an other time/date format.

Have a look here http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Example:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate new];
NSString* format = @"dd MMM yyyy hh:mma'Z'";

NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"SGT"];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:format];
[dateFormat setCalendar: calendar];

NSDate* formatDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]];
```

Can you try this ?

Comment: Problem is I got nil. How shall I do?

Comment: You can display your date in any format you want, I don't think it has to do anything with the device hour format.

Answer (score 1):

The library you are using is bad.  There are other parameters that you need to set on the `NSDateFormatter` that are not being set and are using the system settings.  Don't use `DateTool` just create your own `NSDateFormatter`. In addition to the timezone, and formatString you must also set the **calendar** and the **locale**.

see
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: Thanks. yes I should set those 2 value also. I notice my device locale is chinese. That's why I got nil.